# Calling another form difference in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between these?

**A.)**

```
 Using xForm as New frmCall()
      xForm.ShowDialog()
 End Using
```

**B.)**

```
 Dim xForm as new frmCall()
 xForm.ShowDialog()
 xForm.Dispose
```

**C.)**

```
 frmCall.Show()
```

They are all showing the form, and I know it has a difference. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the Dispose() (which was covered by Reed), Show() and ShowDialog() are a big difference.

ShowDialog() is a blocking call, which means the methods doesn't exit until the dialog you just popped up on the screen has been dismissed. Dialogs sit on top of your application and prevent you from interacting with the other forms beneath. This all is called "modal" behavior.

Show() does not block. The method will make the form visible and then continue on. You can show several forms this way and click/switch between them with no restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

The first two examples are very similar.

The main difference is that, in the first case, the Dispose call will still occur if an exception is raised inside ShowDialog.  In "B", if you raise an exception in ShowDialog, the Dispose call will never occur.

The last option will never call Dispose on the frmCall instance.

Comment: The fact that Dispose is never called does not mean it would never occur. Garbage collection is supposed to take care of that anyway, it's just you never know when.

Comment: @Neolisk The fact that `Dispose()` is never called does mean that it will never occur.  A properly implemented class will still provide a finalizer (when necessary) and call a protected `Dispose(bool)` method from within that finalizer, but the actual `IDisposable.Dispose` method will never be called unless you call it explicitly (or use the variable within a using block)

Comment: I assumed that every class that implements IDisposable will do that, so user will not need to. But you are right, implementations may vary. Sorry for being idealistic.